# LSTM Time Series Classificasion val_acc is fixed or less than 0.5

Tags: pandas, keras, time-series, classification, lstm

After reading and googling my concern is that there is something wrong with my data. The data come from two sources, with deference intervals. I joined the two sources and re-sampled the data so it will have the same intervals with a linear function. Than I scaled the data using StandardScaler. Finally the data was divided to small chunk (60 rows or features - tried different sizes of chunks).

One thing that I noticed that after scaling some features (columns) change a lot -here is a sample of the data:

[image: data sample]

Here one feature is zero. In other samples it changes.

I than tried several configurations:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(4,38)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
chk = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.pkl', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, mode='max', verbose=1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, train_target, epochs=300, batch_size=128, callbacks=[chk], validation_data=(validation,validation_target), shuffle=True)
```

OR:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,init='normal', input_shape=(4, 46)))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(lr=0.00008)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt,  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, train_target, epochs=300, batch_size=128, callbacks=[chk], validation_data=(validation,validation_target), shuffle=True)
```

No matter how many sample - 1000,2000, 5000 - The val accuracy is always about 0.5 or less and is fixed for most of the training:

```
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 485us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 492us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 481us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 471us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 467us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 517us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
333/333 [==============================] - 0s 478us/step - loss: 4.5135 - val_loss: 4.4903
```

Comment: Your LSTM initialization is bad. It should be "xavier". Also, your `lr` is very low

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. sow a post saying reduce the lr.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the data. I learned that before trying different parameters of the network, fixed accuracy or a model that is not improving suggests that there is a problem with the data.